# array management on react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, array.prototype.map

currently doing a recipe MERN project,

so far I have made a button to create an input of new ingredient for user,

however, I am stuck when I tried to add a button for removing current / extra ingredient input field

I tried the code from below
https://codingstatus.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-with-react-js/
using .map to embed the < input> and the < button>

but it doesn't work as expected
the button does not response anything

I feel like it is supposed to work as well
since all the logic makes sense to me
however, not only does the remove button not work, but also the add button fail as well

can someone help me to take a quick look at the code

expected result is there is a remove button to the right of the input field, so user could manage how many ingredient to be put in the recipe

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useGetUserID } from "../Hooks/useGetUserID";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Create_recipe = () => {
  const userId = useGetUserID(); // for below userOwner

  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState({
    name: "",
    ingredient: [],
    instruction: "",
    imageUrl: "",
    cookingTime: 0,
    userOwner: userId,
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate(); // for below push to another page

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleAddIngredient = () => {
    const newIngredient = [...recipe.ingredient, ""];
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, newIngredient });
  };

  const handleRemoveIngredient = (index) => {
    const updatedIngredient = [...recipe.ingredient];
    updatedIngredient.splice(index, 1);
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, updatedIngredient });
  };

  const handleIngredientChange = (event, index) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = event.target;

    const ingredient = [...recipe.ingredient];
    ingredient[index] = value;
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, ingredient }); //short handed notation
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/recipe/create",
        data: recipe,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      });

      alert("recipe created");
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) alert(JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="createRecipeSession">
      <h2 className="createRecipeHeader">Create Recipe</h2>
      <div className="createRecipeContainer">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="createFormDetail">
          <div className="createRecipeSubtitle">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          </div>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={handleChange} />

          <div className="createRecipeSubtitle">
            <label htmlFor="ingredients">Ingredients</label>
          </div>
          <div>
          {recipe.ingredient.map((ingredient, index) => (
            <div className="ingredientOption" key={index}>
              <div className="ingredientOption1">
                <input
                  className="inputIngredient"
                  type="text"
                  name="ingredient"
                  value={ingredient}
                  onChange={(event) => handleIngredientChange(event, index)}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="ingredientOption2">
                {recipe.ingredient.length !== 1 ? (
                  <button
                    className="removeIngredient"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveIngredient(index)}
                  > - </button>) : ""}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
          <button
            className="addIngredient"
            type="button"
            onClick={handleAddIngredient}>Add ingredient</button>
          </div>
          
          <div className="createRecipeSubtitle">
            <label htmlFor="instruction">Instruction</label>
          </div>
          <textarea
            id="instruction"
            name="instruction"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <div className="createRecipeSubtitle">
            <label htmlFor="imageUrl">ImageUrl</label>
          </div>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="imageUrl"
            name="imageUrl"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />

          <div className="createRecipeSubtitle">
            <label htmlFor="cookingTime">CookingTime</label>
          </div>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="cookingTime"
            name="cookingTime"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button className="createRecipeButton" type="submit">
            Create recipe
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Create_recipe;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `handleRemoveIngredient()` when setting the recipe state with `setRecipe` you're adding everything you had before and a new property called `updatedIngredient`, what you have to do is replace the `ingredient` property.

```
const handleRemoveIngredient = (index) => {
    const updatedIngredient = [...recipe.ingredient];
    updatedIngredient.splice(index, 1);
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, ingredient: updatedIngredient });
  };
```

The same for the `handleAddIngredient()` function, and ideally you would pass a value, which is going to be the new ingredient

```
const handleAddIngredient = (value) => {
    const newIngredient = [...recipe.ingredient, value];
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, ingredient: newIngredient });
};
```

Comment: ahhh thanks. I overlooked this one 
just amended it, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: could you add some ingredients when initializing state and try deleting them with the function from my answer?

Comment: even the add ingredient button fail to response now ,
dunno where went wrong,
has been looking for the reason
@Victor Santizo

Comment: OMG it works now,
should have not deleted that,
I thought that is duplicated element,